# conda $PATH (zsh) is incorrect in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, zsh, conda, jupyter-lab

I have an issue with `$PATH` in Jupyter lab. In my terminal (not Jupyter lab), Conda paths are added correctly at the beginning of `$PATH`

```
echo $PATH
```

```
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:
/Library/Apple/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

In Jupyter lab terminal, the Conda paths are added at the end of `$PATH`.

```
echo $PATH
```

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:
/Library/Apple/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin
```

Currently, the Conda paths are added by

```
usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

and I cannot find any problem in this script.

I think I can just modify `.zshrc`, but I want to know why this happen and how can I fix it without manually adding paths in `.zshrc`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a self-answer.

This is just a bug in Jupyter notebook. The `$PATH` is inherited from the original terminal that launched Jupyter. However, it scrambles the order of the PATHs.

One workaround is to use Conda (or any environment control). In the terminal (Jupyter), deactivate the environment and reactivate it. Then it will add the necessary paths at the beginning.

```
conda deactivate
conda activate base
```